# Image not showing in .blade file

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel, but why the hell is this not working?

`<img src='../img/netflix_logo.png' />`

I've tried using `php artisan storage:link` and it said `The [C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-crud\public\storage] link has been connected to [C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-crud\storage\app/public]. The links have been created.` but the image is still not displaying in my .blade page..

Comment: The .blade file is in `/resources/views` and the image is in `resources/img`

Comment: Files in the `resources` folder won't be publicly available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you image is in storage/img then

```
<img src="{{ url('storage/img/netflix_logo.png') }}" alt="" title="" />
```

If you image is in public/img folder then

```
<img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/img/netflix_logo.png" alt="" title="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use the "asset" helper from `laravel/blade`:

```
asset('/path/of/your/image')
```

It's the common way to call a static file from public folder (including storage if you already linked it)